# Correcting a DNA scoring algorithm for scanned sequence length (consensus binding site)

Tags: algorithms, bioinformatics, genetics

In [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2441782/), the authors present a scoring algorithm for potential transcription factor binding sites, based on the position-specific probability matrix (PSPM) for that particular transcription factor.

The binding site is 20 nucleotides long, so the idea is to scan a longer DNA sequence in 20 nucleotide chunks, i.e. score site 1 (nucleotides 1-20), then score site 2 (nucleotides 2-21), etc.

The score of each site is given by:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{20} \ln \left[\frac{f_{i,b}}{g} + 0.01\right] $$

where $i$ represents the position in the consensus binding sequence, and $f_{i,b}$ is the probability of the nucleotide that happens to be in the long DNA sequence occurring at position $i$ in the binding site, and $g$ is the background frequency of that nucleotide (the authors assume it be be 0.25, that is, an equal probability of each nucleotide).

**To illustrate:**
Say your PSPM starts with row 1 being $[0.2 $ $0.3$ $0.5$ $0]$. This means at position 1 in the potential binding sites (row 1), there is a 20% probability of having an A (Adenine), a 30% chance of having a C (Cytosine), a 50% probability of having a G (Guanine), and a 0% probability of having a T (Thymine). If you happen to be scoring a subsequence that has a C in the first position, the first term of the sum, $ \ln \left(\frac{f_{1,b}}{g} + 0.01\right) $, would be $ \ln \left(\frac{0.3}{g} + 0.01\right) $.

This procedure doesn't at all account for length of the sequence you're scanning. Thus, longer sequences are going to have higher-scoring sites, and I would like to be able to compare sites between sequences of different lengths.

How could I correct this algorithm for sequence length?